# How can I fix my backend dashboard buttons?

Tags: admin, magento-1, backend

I've recently taken over a website with an older version of Magento (1.6).  I upgraded (since the site was never built and the owner wanted a new theme) and now the buttons in the backend dashboard are a little zonky.  Each button shows three of the button image, like this:

[image: I've tried reinstalling the Magento interface applications, but with] no luck. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: clear the browser cache.

Comment: I had already refreshed the browser cache, I should have detailed that in the post.  Jonazu's suggestion to replace app/design/adminhtml/default/default and skin/adminhtml/default/default resolved the issue.

Comment: Then a +1 for him :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading to 1.9. I think I solved it by deleting

- app/design/adminhtml/default/default
- skin/adminhtml/default/default

And of course reuploading from a fresh Magento 1.9 installation/download package.

Answer (score 1):

```
skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
```

search for: `.form-buttons`

set: `margin:2px -3px 2px 0px;`

was: `margin:2px -3px 2px 0pt;`

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer, but I have just added because I was also facing this issue and I didn't find a better solution.

I have just added 1 line css to **boxes.css**. And it is as below:

> button span span {
>       background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
>       display: inline !important;
>       margin: 0 !important;
>       padding: 0 !important; }